# UITableView using UIViewController not loading tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following layout whereby I have my searchbar at the top and does not scroll with tableView.  I have wired up the datasource and delegate for UITableView with my custom UIViewControler but I am not getting my tableview populated but instead I am getting the error below.  Please can someone advise?

My Layout:

[image]

[image]

TestTableViewController - inspecter:[image]

TestTableViewController:

```
 class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{


@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
var itemstore: ItemStore!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsSection ...")
    return itemstore.allItems.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRow ...")
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    let name = itemstore.allItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = name

    return cell
}
```

ItemStore:

```
 import UIKit

 class ItemStore {

var allItems = ["Thanh", "David", "Tommy", "Maria"]


 }
```

AppDelegate:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Create ItemStore instance
    let itemStoreObject = ItemStore()
    let itemController = window!.rootViewController as! TestTableViewController
    itemController.itemstore = itemStoreObject

    return true
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 2017-06-16 21:30:33.046 TestTableViewSearch[15419:1672786] *** Assertion 
 failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], 
 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-
 3600.6.21/UITableView.m:8042
 2017-06-16 21:30:33.052 TestTableViewSearch[15419:1672786] *** Terminating 
 app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fa6e3817a00; frame = (0 64; 375 603); 
 clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 
 0x600000058f60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000025680>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; 
 contentSize: {375, 176}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource 
 (<TestTableViewSearch.TestTableViewController: 0x7fa6e2406df0>)'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c39d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010df4c21e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110c3de42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x000000010dae166d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   UIKit                               0x000000010e57d9cd -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 222
5   UIKit                               0x000000010e5895eb -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 860
6   UIKit                               0x000000010e5897e2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
7   UIKit                               0x000000010e55d2b0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
8   UIKit                               0x000000010e592b64 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
9   UIKit                               0x000000010e5793be -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
10  UIKit                               0x000000010e4e0ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a7fbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a73440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a732be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a01318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a2e3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113a2ed6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bde267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bde1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110bc28a6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
20  UIKit                               0x000000010e415aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
21  UIKit                               0x000000010e41bc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
22  TestTableViewSearch                 0x000000010d96299f main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111be968d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

means that your code is not handling `UITableViewDataSource` properly. It might be due to `UITableViewDataSource` not implemented correctly or there might be some error in assigning the *datasource* and *delegate* properties in the xib.

**Mistake :**

I notice that your class `TestTableViewController`, does not conform to protocol `UITableViewDataSource`

So make your class `TestTableViewController` conform to protocol `UITableViewDataSource` like so :

```
class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate , UITableViewDataSource
```

and define `UITableViewDataSource` methods in `TestTableViewController`.

Comment: Actually that image shows the outlets of the TestTableViewController, so that is showing there's a dataSource and delegate outlet, from My Table View to TestTableViewController. And from the stack trace we can see the dataSource is an instance of TestTableViewController

Comment: @Jota  Ahh I see.. I must have missed it in a hurry. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer to accommodate the change you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows:

> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Your view controller is:

`class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{`

Which appears to be missing `UITableViewDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

We can see in the stack trace the actual error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:  'UITableView (...) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<TestTableViewSearch.TestTableViewController: 0x7fa6e2406df0>)'"`

That means that your cellForRowAtIndexPath method returned a nil cell. You need to specify a reuse identifier for the cell in the Storyboard and init it like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
```

Also in the stack trace we can see that the data source is actually correct:

```
(...) dataSource  (<TestTableViewSearch.TestTableViewController: 0x7fa6e2406df0>)'"
```

So you only need to return a valid cell and it should work.